# Is it a better option to change a include_path parameter in php.ini?

Tags: php

If we want to change the path our included php file by `include()` function repeatedly.

As for example i want to include the file **security.php** so by default i have to set the whole path as

*/usr/local/php/projectx/security/* and after setting the `include_path()` as per the desired path(*/usr/local/php/projectx/security/* ) in

`php.ini` i'll just need to include the file as *security.php* for the script needed.

By which i can finally achieve (*/usr/local/php/projectx/security/security.php*)

So,is it a better option for future purspose?

Comment: Use composer and the PSR-4 autoloader.  The autoloader was created to solve this exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can, however this should not be needed if you are using a framework.

If you are not using a framework, and going with plain PHP, you should architect your code, and what includes what, instead of changing the value in php.ini

Also, instead of absolute path, you can use relative path like:

`include('../security.php');`

or  `include('./projectx/security.php');`

Depending on where you do the include from.

You can also utilize [Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php):

Comment: I thought it the same way.Thanks for you suggestion.